# Monthly Actual Cost vs Monthly Contract Amount

Tags: sql

I have a project that pulls cost per category (labor, equipment, indirect), per month for a job and then shows a running, cumulative total of the contract amount per month. (This calculation is based on the total contract amount divided by the number of months in a project. Then the second month is the first month + second month, third month is first month + second month + third month, etc.)

I have the query shown below. When I run this, it returns the data shown under current results. What I need is the running total column populated even when there are no costs as shown under expected results. How do I accomplish this?

**Current results:**

| fiscalMonth | Labor | Equipment | Indirect | RunningTotal | ContractPerMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-01-01 | 6518.78 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 2141444.44 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-02-01 | 8563.68 | 0.00 | 58.81 | 4282888.88 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-03-01 | 7271.28 | 429.14 | 139167.21 | 6424333.32 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-04-01 | 44538.32 | 2117.64 | 59379.53 | 8565777.76 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-05-01 | -14932.44 | 2476.85 | 1279972.38 | 10707222.20 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-06-01 | 3701.65 | 250.00 | 992.45 | 12848666.64 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-07-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-08-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

**Expected results:**

| fiscalMonth | Labor | Equipment | Indirect | RunningTotal | ContractPerMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 2141444.44 | 0.00 |
| 2022-01-01 | 6518.78 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 4282888.88 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-02-01 | 8563.68 | 0.00 | 58.81 | 6424333.32 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-03-01 | 7271.28 | 429.14 | 139167.21 | 8565777.76 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-04-01 | 44538.32 | 2117.64 | 59379.53 | 10707222.20 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-05-01 | -14932.44 | 2476.85 | 1279972.38 | 12848666.64 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-06-01 | 3701.65 | 250.00 | 992.45 | 14990111.08 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-07-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 17131555.52 | 2141444.44 |
| 2022-08-01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 19272999.96 | 0.00 |

```
Create Table #costs(fiscalMonth date, Labor numeric(12,2), Equipment numeric(12,2), Indirect numeric(12,2), RunningTotal numeric(12,2), ContractPerMonth numeric(12,2))

Declare @startDate as date, @endDate as date, @lastMonth as date,@count int

select @startDate = StartMonth, @endDate = ProjCloseDate from JCCM
WHERE
ltrim(rtrim(Contract)) = (@Job)

insert into #costs
SELECT
    Mth
    ,isnull(Sum(LaborCost),0) as LaborCost
    ,Isnull(Sum(EquipmentCost),0) as EquipmentCost
    ,isnull(Sum(IndirectCost),0) as IndirectCost
    ,SUM (ContractAmtPerMonth) OVER (ORDER BY Mth) AS RunningTotal
    ,ContractAmtPerMonth


FROM(
SELECT
    cp.Mth
    ,CASE WHEN ct.JBCostTypeCategory = 'L' THEN SUM(cp.ActualCost) END as LaborCost
    ,CASE WHEN ct.JBCostTypeCategory = 'E' THEN SUM(cp.ActualCost) END as EquipmentCost
    ,CASE WHEN ct.JBCostTypeCategory = 'O' THEN SUM(cp.ActualCost) END as IndirectCost
    ,(Select CASE WHEN Sum(cm.ContractAmt) <> 0 THEN CAST(SUM(cm.ContractAmt / ((DATEDIFF(Month,cm.StartMonth,cm.ProjCloseDate)+1))) as numeric(12,2)) END from JCCM cm WHERE  cm.JCCo = jm.JCCo and cm.Contract = jm.Contract) as ContractAmtPerMonth


FROM
    JCCP cp
    LEFT JOIN JCCT ct ON cp.PhaseGroup = ct.PhaseGroup AND cp.CostType = ct.CostType
    LEFT JOIN JCJM jm ON cp.JCCo = jm.JCCo and cp.Job = jm.Job

WHERE
    cp.JCCo IN (@Company)
    AND ltrim(rtrim(cp.Job)) = (@Job)
    AND ct.JBCostTypeCategory IN ('L','E','O')
GROUP BY
    jm.JCCo
    ,jm.Job
    ,jm.Contract
    ,cp.Mth
    ,ct.JBCostTypeCategory

)cost

    
GROUP BY
    Mth
    ,ContractAmtPerMonth


WHILE (@startDate <= @endDate)

BEGIN

    print CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(@endDate AS VARCHAR(10))
    select @count = Count (*) from #costs
    print @count
    if Not exists(select 1 from #costs where fiscalMonth = @startDate)
    begin
    insert into #costs (fiscalMonth, Labor, Equipment, Indirect,RunningTotal,  ContractPerMonth ) values (@startDate,0,0,0,0,0)
    end

    set @startDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @startDate);

END
select * from #costs order by fiscalMonth
Drop table #costs
```

Comment: So the running total is just the contract per month multiplied by the number of months? It doesn't include the labor/equipment/indirect costs for the month? Also, the labor/equipment/indirect costs are just totals for that month, they are not running totals?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure out how to accomplish what I needed. I modified how I created my table (changed table name from #costs to #months). This pulled the months, row number, and contract amount. I then joined it to my existing cost query. In SSRS, I'm able to calculate the running total by multiplying the monthly contract amount by the row number. Seems to be working.

```
create table #months  (JCCo numeric, Job varchar(10), StartDate date, EndDate date)
    
 insert into #months 
  
 SELECT JCCo,Contract,StartMonth, ProjCloseDate  FROM JCCM WHERE JCCo = (@Company) AND Contract = (@Job);
    
   
  with Q1 as
 (
     select JCCo,Job,StartDate as Mth
     from #months
     union all
     select q.JCCo,q.Job,DATEADD(m, 1, q.Mth)
     from Q1 q
     inner join #months t on t.Job = q.Job
     where Mth <= (DATEADD(MONTH,-1,t.EndDate))
     
)
  
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Q1.Job, Q1.Mth) as Row#, Q1.JCCo, Q1.Job, Q1.Mth as fiscalMonth, ISNULL(cd.LaborCost,0) as Labor, ISNULL(cd.EquipmentCost,0) as Equipment, ISNULL(cd.IndirectCost,0) as Indirect, CAST(cm.ContractAmt / ((DATEDIFF(Month,cm.StartMonth,cm.ProjCloseDate)+1)) as DECIMAL(12,2)) as MonthlyContract, cm.ContractAmt as TotalContract
 from Q1
```